# Newcommand options and for each

Tags: macros, foreach

I have defined a new command `\case`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\newcommand\case[1]{
\ifx 1#1 case 1\else
\ifx 2#1 case 2\else
\ifx 3#1 case 3\else
Illegal
\fi\fi\fi
}

\begin{document}

\case{1}

\case{2}

\case{3}

\end{document}
```

The new command works fine:

```
\case{1}: case 1
\case{2}: case 2
\case{3}: case 3
```

But with for each result:

```
\foreach \x in {1,2,3}{\case{\x}}
```

Illegal Illegal Illegal

Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: there is a primitive `\ifcase`  that lets you branch on 0,1,2

Comment: please show an example of the problem that you are asking for help with, in your final fragment neither `\foreach `nor `\doc` are defined. And you do not say what error you got.

Comment: note that with your definition  `\case{12}` produces the text `2 case 1`

Comment: so you do not mean you got a tex error you just got the expected output `illegal illegal illegal;` from the foreach macro (presumably from tikz, although you do not mention that package)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is unrelated to `foreach` you would see the same from `\def\x{1}  \case{\x}`

You are comparing `\ifx 1\x` and the tokens 1 and `\x` are not the same so this is false.

Conversely `\case{12}` would test `\ifx112`  which would test 1 and 1 as true and then typeset 2.

You want to do a numeric test not test the unexpanded tokens, so

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\case[1]{%
\ifcase\numexpr#1\relax
case 0\or
case 1\or
case 2\or
case 3\else
Illegal%
\fi}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\case{1}

\case{12}

\case{3}


\foreach \x in {1,2,3}{\case{\x}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you David for your solution, it works well.

Answer (score 4):

I can propose a more flexible set of commands.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
%\usepackage{xparse} % uncomment if using LaTeX released before 2020-10-01

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\checkcases}{mmO{}m}
 {
  \int_case:nnTF { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\mycaseswitch}[1]{%
  \checkcases{#1}{
    {1}{Case 1}
    {2}{Case 2}
    {3}{Case 3}
    {42}{Ultimate}
  }{Illegal}%
}
\newcommand{\otherswitch}[1]{%
  \checkcases{#1}{
    {-2}{Negative}
    {2}{Positive}
  }[!]{Bad?}%
}

\begin{document}

\mycaseswitch{1}: case 1

\mycaseswitch{2}: case 2

\mycaseswitch{3}: case 3

\mycaseswitch{4}: illegal

\mycaseswitch{42}: Hey!

\foreach \x in {1,2,3}{\mycaseswitch{\x}\par}

\otherswitch{-2}

\otherswitch{2}

\otherswitch{0}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `\checkcases` command is just an interface to the internal `expl3` function `\int_case:nnTF`. It has four arguments:

1. the integer to test against the case list;
2. the case list, in the form of pairs `{<integer>}{<text>}` (no need that the integers are consecutive or start from 0 like for `\ifcase`); spaces are ignored between pairs;
3. (optional) text to be used after a successful match;
4. text to be used for “no match”.

Comment: Thank you egreg for your solution and suggestions, it is very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

With your code the `\foreach`-loop passes the token `\x` as argument to the `\case`-macro. `\ifx` (within the definition-text of `\case`) does compare the meaning of tokens without expanding them.

Therefore

- via `\ifx` the meaning of the explicit character-token `112` is compared to the meaning of the control-sequence-token `\x` while the meanings differ,
- via `\ifx` the meaning of the explicit character-token `212` is compared to the meaning of the control-sequence-token `\x` while the meanings differ,
- via `\ifx` the meaning of the explicit character-token `312` is compared to the meaning of the control-sequence-token `\x` while the meanings differ.

Thus things end up in the "illegal"-branch.

With `\foreach` ensuring that control-sequences serving as loop-variable are expanded properly is up to the user.

Try: `\foreach \x in {1,2,3}{\expandafter\case\expandafter{\x}}`

By the way:

`\case` may behave in unexpected ways in case somebody provides things as `#1` which contain unbalanced `\else` and/or `\fi` which match up the `\ifx`-expressions within the *⟨definition text⟩*  of `\case`. Try, e.g., `\case{4\fi\iftrue}`.

---

For the sake of having fun while implementing it I can offer a macro `\ExtractKthArg` which does fully expandable without any additional package and without any `\if..\fi` and which cannot be tricked by unbalanced `\else` or `\fi` within its argument:

Syntax:

```
\ExtractKthArg{⟨TeX-⟨number⟩-quantity denoting an integer of value K⟩}%
              {⟨tokens in case list of undelimited arguments doesn't have a K-th argument⟩}%
              {⟨list of undelimited arguments⟩}%
```

**In case there is no K-th argument in *⟨list of undelimited arguments⟩* :**

Does deliver *⟨tokens in case list of undelimited arguments doesn't have a K-th argument⟩*.

**In case there is a K-th argument in *⟨list of undelimited arguments⟩* :**

Does deliver that K-th argument with one level of braces removed.

Examples:

`\ExtractKthArg{0}{not available}{ABCDE}` yields: `not available`

`\ExtractKthArg{3}{not available}{ABCDE}` yields:  `C`

`\ExtractKthArg{3}{not available}{AB{CD}E}` yields:  `CD`

`\ExtractKthArg{4}{not available}{{001}{002}{003}{004}{005}}` yields: `004`

`\ExtractKthArg{6}{not available}{{001}{002}{003}}` yields: `not available`

**As long as the argument of your `\case`-macro will in any case be a valid TeX-*⟨number⟩*-quantity** and you want TeX-*⟨number⟩*-quantities with values from 1 to 3 to be "legal", you can easily implement `\case` as follows by means of `\ExtractKthArg`:

```
\newcommand\case[1]{%
  \ExtractKthArg{#1}{illegal}{{case 1}{case 2}{case 3}}%
}%
```

Here comes the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
%% Code for \ExtractKthArg
%%=============================================================================
%% Paraphernalia:
%%    \UD@firstoftwo, \UD@secondoftwo, \UD@PassFirstToSecond, 
%%    \UD@CheckWhetherNull,
%%=============================================================================
\newcommand\UD@firstoftwo[2]{#1}%
\newcommand\UD@secondoftwo[2]{#2}%
\newcommand\UD@PassFirstToSecond[2]{#2{#1}}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument is empty:
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherNull{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is empty>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is not empty>}%
%%
%% The gist of this macro comes from Robert R. Schneck's \ifempty-macro:
%% <https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.text.tex/kuOEIQIrElc/lUg37FmhA74J>
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNull[1]{%
  \romannumeral\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\z@\UD@secondoftwo}%
  {\expandafter\z@\UD@firstoftwo}%
}%
%%=============================================================================
%% Extract K-th inner undelimited argument:
%%
%% \ExtractKthArg{<TeX-<number>-quantity denoting an integer of value K>}%
%%               {<tokens in case list of undelimited arguments doesn't have a K-th argument>}%
%%               {<list of undelimited arguments>} %
%% 
%% In case there is no K-th argument in <list of undelimited arguments> : 
%%   Does deliver <tokens in case list of undelimited arguments doesn't have a K-th argument>.
%% In case there is a K-th argument in <list of undelimited arguments> : 
%%   Does deliver that K-th argument with one level of braces removed.
%%
%% Examples:
%%
%%   \ExtractKthArg{0}{not available}{ABCDE} yields: not available
%%
%%   \ExtractKthArg{3}{not available}{ABCDE} yields:  C
%%
%%   \ExtractKthArg{3}{not available}{AB{CD}E} yields:  CD
%%
%%   \ExtractKthArg{4}{not available}{{001}{002}{003}{004}{005}} yields: 004
%%
%%   \ExtractKthArg{6}{not available}{{001}{002}{003}} yields: not available 
%% 
%%=============================================================================
\newcommand\ExtractKthArg[2]{%
  \romannumeral%
  % #1: <TeX-<number>-quantity denoting an integer of value K>
  % #2: <tokens in case list of undelimited arguments doesn't have a K-th argumnent>
  \expandafter\UD@ExtractKthArgCheck
  \expandafter{\romannumeral\number\number#1 000}{#2}%
}%
\newcommand\UD@ExtractKthArgCheck[3]{%
  \UD@CheckWhetherNull{#1}{% K not positive:
    \z@#2%
  }{% K positive:
    \expandafter\UD@ExtractKthArgLoop\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#1}{#2}{#3}%
  }%
}%
\newcommand\UD@ExtractKthArgLoop[3]{%
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo#3{}.}{\z@#2}{%
    \UD@CheckWhetherNull{#1}{%
      \UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop{#3\UD@SelDOm}%
    }{%
      \expandafter\UD@PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#3}%
      {\expandafter\UD@ExtractKthArgLoop\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#1}{#2}}%
    }%
  }%
}%
\newcommand\UD@RemoveTillUD@SelDOm{}%
\long\def\UD@RemoveTillUD@SelDOm#1#2\UD@SelDOm{{#1}}%
\newcommand\UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop[1]{%
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#1}%
  {\expandafter\z@\UD@secondoftwo{}#1}%
  {\expandafter\UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop\expandafter{\UD@RemoveTillUD@SelDOm#1}}%
}%
%% End of code for \ExtractKthArg.
\makeatother

\usepackage{pgffor}

\newcommand\case[1]{%
  \ExtractKthArg{#1}{illegal}{{case 1}{case 2}{case 3}}%
}%

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\verb|\case{1}|: \case{1}

\verb|\case{2}|: \case{2}

\verb|\case{3}|: \case{3}

\verb|\case{-1}|: \case{-1}

\verb|\case{4}|: \case{4}

The \verb|\foreach|-loop:

\verb|\foreach \x in {1,2,3}{\case{\x}}|: 

\foreach \x in {1,2,3}{\case{\x}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**In case it is not ensured that the argument of your `\case`-macro will in any case be a valid TeX-*⟨number⟩*-quantity**, things are more complicated:

Strictly spoken it is not possible to test whether an arbitrary macro argument yields a valid TeX-*⟨number⟩*-quantity: TeX is said to be Turing-complete. An arbitrary macro argument forms an arbitrary expansion-based algorithm. Checking whether an arbitrary expansion-based algorithm yields a valid TeX-*⟨number⟩*-quantity implies checking whether the arbitrary expansion-based algorithm in question (carried out by a system which is Turing-complete) terminates at all. This is the halting-problem.  Alan Turing proved in 1936 that a general algorithm to solve the halting problem for all possible program-input pairs cannot exist.

But if you restrict to a -eh- bulletable list of constellations of tokens as "legal" user-input, then you can implement mapping from the single "legal" constellations to numbers and use that mapping when calling `\ExtractKthArg`:

Assume you wish only the token-constellation `A11112` and the token-constellation `a11112` and the token-constellation `B11212` and the token-constellation`b11212` and the token-constellation `C11312` and the token-constellation `c11312` to be allowed as legal user-input,
both `A11112` and `a11112` yielding the phrase `case a1 or A1`,
both `B11212` and `b11212` yielding the phrase `case b2 or B2`,
both `C11312` and `c11212` yielding the phrase `case c3 or C3`.
You can implement forking/mapping by means of delimited arguments as follows:

The token(-sequence) `!12` is not a component of any of the token-constellations which are considered legal user-input. Therefore this token(-sequence) can be used as component of an argument-delimiter. But you need to test whether the argument passed by the user contains this token(-sequence) in order to ensure that no weird things happen in case the user provided something that would match up the argument-delimiter in some erroneous way:

```
% Code for a mechanism which forks illegal user-input and the
% different cases of legal user-input and maps these cases to 
% numbers:
\@ifdefinable{\GobbleToExclam}{\long\def\GobbleToExclam#1!{}}%
\@ifdefinable\CaseSelect{%
  \long\def\CaseSelect#1!a1!A1!b2!B2!c3!C3!#2#3!!!{#2}%
}%
\newcommand\MapCasesToNumbers[1]{%
  % Check whether an argument contains no exclamation-mark of
  % catcode 12 which is not nested in braces:
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\GobbleToExclam#1!}{%
    % Something without exclamation-mark, so let's select a case by
    % means of \CaseSelect where exclamation-mark is a component of
    % the argument-delimiter:
    \CaseSelect
    !#1!A1!b2!B2!c3!C3!{1}% <- Case #1 = a1
    !a1!#1!b2!B2!c3!C3!{1}% <- Case #1 = A1
    !a1!A1!#1!B2!c3!C3!{2}% <- Case #1 = b2
    !a1!A1!b2!#1!c3!C3!{2}% <- Case #1 = B2
    !a1!A1!b2!B2!#1!C3!{3}% <- Case #1 = c3
    !a1!A1!b2!B2!c3!#1!{3}% <- Case #1 = C3
    !a1!A1!b2!B2!c3!C3!{4}% <- Case #1 = s.th. else without exclamation-mark
    !!!%
  }{4}% <- Case #1 = s.th. else with exclamation-mark
}%
% End of code for a mechanism which forks illegal user-input
% and the different cases of legal user-input and maps these
% cases to numbers.
```

If you do it this way, ensuring that, e.g., macros serving as loop-variable of `\pgffor` are expanded properly before the forking-mechanism is applied is up to you.

Putting the pieces together:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
%% Code for \ExtractKthArg
%%=============================================================================
%% Paraphernalia:
%%    \UD@firstoftwo, \UD@secondoftwo, \UD@PassFirstToSecond, 
%%    \UD@CheckWhetherNull,
%%=============================================================================
\newcommand\UD@firstoftwo[2]{#1}%
\newcommand\UD@secondoftwo[2]{#2}%
\newcommand\UD@PassFirstToSecond[2]{#2{#1}}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument is empty:
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherNull{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is empty>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is not empty>}%
%%
%% The gist of this macro comes from Robert R. Schneck's \ifempty-macro:
%% <https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.text.tex/kuOEIQIrElc/lUg37FmhA74J>
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNull[1]{%
  \romannumeral\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\z@\UD@secondoftwo}%
  {\expandafter\z@\UD@firstoftwo}%
}%
%%=============================================================================
%% Extract K-th inner undelimited argument:
%%
%% \ExtractKthArg{<TeX-<number>-quantity denoting an integer of value K>}%
%%               {<tokens in case list of undelimited args doesn't have a K-th argument>}%
%%               {<list of undelimited arguments>} %
%% 
%% In case there is no K-th argument in <list of undelimited arguments> : 
%%   Does deliver <tokens in case list of undelimited arguments doesn't have a K-th argument>.
%% In case there is a K-th argument in <list of undelimited arguments> : 
%%   Does deliver that K-th argument with one level of braces removed.
%%
%% Examples:
%%
%%   \ExtractKthArg{0}{not available}{ABCDE} yields: not available
%%
%%   \ExtractKthArg{3}{not available}{ABCDE} yields:  C
%%
%%   \ExtractKthArg{3}{not available}{AB{CD}E} yields:  CD
%%
%%   \ExtractKthArg{4}{not available}{{001}{002}{003}{004}{005}} yields: 004
%%
%%   \ExtractKthArg{6}{not available}{{001}{002}{003}} yields: not available 
%% 
%%=============================================================================
\newcommand\ExtractKthArg[2]{%
  \romannumeral%
  % #1: <TeX-<number>-quantity denoting an integer of value K>
  % #2: <tokens in case list of undelimited arguments doesn't have a K-th argument>
  \expandafter\UD@ExtractKthArgCheck
  \expandafter{\romannumeral\number\number#1 000}{#2}%
}%
\newcommand\UD@ExtractKthArgCheck[3]{%
  \UD@CheckWhetherNull{#1}{% K not positive:
    \z@#2%
  }{% K positive:
    \expandafter\UD@ExtractKthArgLoop\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#1}{#2}{#3}%
  }%
}%
\newcommand\UD@ExtractKthArgLoop[3]{%
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo#3{}.}{\z@#2}{%
    \UD@CheckWhetherNull{#1}{%
      \UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop{#3\UD@SelDOm}%
    }{%
      \expandafter\UD@PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#3}%
      {\expandafter\UD@ExtractKthArgLoop\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#1}{#2}}%
    }%
  }%
}%
\newcommand\UD@RemoveTillUD@SelDOm{}%
\long\def\UD@RemoveTillUD@SelDOm#1#2\UD@SelDOm{{#1}}%
\newcommand\UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop[1]{%
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#1}%
  {\expandafter\z@\UD@secondoftwo{}#1}%
  {\expandafter\UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop\expandafter{\UD@RemoveTillUD@SelDOm#1}}%
}%
%% End of code for \ExtractKthArg.
\makeatother

\makeatletter    
% Code for a mechanism which forks illegal user-input and the
% different cases of legal user-input and maps these cases to 
% numbers:
\@ifdefinable{\GobbleToExclam}{\long\def\GobbleToExclam#1!{}}%
\@ifdefinable\CaseSelect{%
  \long\def\CaseSelect#1!a1!A1!b2!B2!c3!C3!#2#3!!!{#2}%
}%
\newcommand\MapCasesToNumbers[1]{%
  % Check whether an argument contains no exclamation-mark of
  % catcode 12 which is not nested in braces:
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\GobbleToExclam#1!}{%
    % Something without exclamation-mark, so let's select a case by
    % means of \CaseSelect where exclamation-mark is a component of
    % the argument-delimiter:
    \CaseSelect
    !#1!A1!b2!B2!c3!C3!{1}% <- Case #1 = a1
    !a1!#1!b2!B2!c3!C3!{1}% <- Case #1 = A1
    !a1!A1!#1!B2!c3!C3!{2}% <- Case #1 = b2
    !a1!A1!b2!#1!c3!C3!{2}% <- Case #1 = B2
    !a1!A1!b2!B2!#1!C3!{3}% <- Case #1 = c3
    !a1!A1!b2!B2!c3!#1!{3}% <- Case #1 = C3
    !a1!A1!b2!B2!c3!C3!{4}% <- Case #1 = s.th. else without exclamation-mark
    !!!%
  }{4}% <- Case #1 = s.th. else with exclamation-mark
}%
% End of code for a mechanism which forks illegal user-input
% and the different cases of legal user-input and maps these
% cases to numbers.
\makeatother

\usepackage{pgffor}

\newcommand\case[1]{%
  \ExtractKthArg{\MapCasesToNumbers{#1}}{illegal case}{{case a1 or A1}{case b2 or B2}{case c3 or C3}}%
}%

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\verb|\case{a1}|: \case{a1}

\verb|\case{A1}|: \case{A1}

\verb|\case{b2}|: \case{b2}

\verb|\case{B2}|: \case{B2}

\verb|\case{c3}|: \case{c3}

\verb|\case{C3}|: \case{C3}

\verb|\case{Something Weird \relax \csname \fi}|: \case{Something Weird \relax \csname \fi}

\verb|\case{D4}|: \case{D4}

The \verb|\foreach|-loop---you need to ensure that the loop-variable \verb|\x| is expanded properly:

\verb|\foreach \x in {a1,A1,b2,B2,c3,C3,Weird}{\expandafter\case\expandafter{\x}}|:

\foreach \x in {a1,A1,b2,B2,c3,C3,Weird}{\expandafter\case\expandafter{\x}}

\end{document}
```

[image]